# $(this).closest not working when added to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Hello I have a very basic script that moves the child `<img>` inside its `<label>` parent when you hover on and off the `<label>` element.

The issue is if you hover over one label. ALL images under ALL labels move.. This i do not want. I tried to solve this by adding `$(this).closest` to my function. But when `$(this).closest` code is added it breaks. If you remove (this).closest from my code it works fine but its affecting all of them instead of the single one being hovered over.

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox-cover images-true">
<div>
<label> <img></img> </label>
<label> <img></img> </label>
<label> <img></img> </label>
<label> <img></img> </label>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".checkbox-cover.images-true>div>label").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).closest('img').stop().animate({top: '-200px'});
    }, function (){
        $(this).closest('img').stop().animate({top: '0'});        
});
```

Comment: `closest` searches the DOM tree going **UP**, not **DOWN**, what you really want is `$(this).find('> img')` instead.

Comment: So how do i make the script work by only affecting the current hovered element not all with that class?

Comment: Replace `closest` with `find`!

Comment: I assumed "this" was refering to the <label> ??

Comment: This is once again a prime example of making stuff harder on yourself than it had to be, by using JS to implement something that can be done in CSS already …

Comment: Thanks "find" worked

Comment: It is referring to the label, which is why when you go **_up_** you find a div and then another div.  The image tags are inside, so you use `find()`, as already stated.

Comment: I had to use js lol. I have other code disallowing the use of css animate property.

Comment: Oh thats good to know, thanks archer

Answer (score 4):

[`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches the DOM tree going **up** (ancestors), not **down** (descendants), what you really want is [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.

```
$(".checkbox-cover.images-true > div > label").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('> img').stop().animate({top: '-200px'});
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('> img').stop().animate({top: '0'})
    });        
});
```

Lastly, as the comments suggest, you can shorten `$(this).find('> img')` with `$('img', this)`, setting the "context" parameter.

Comment: Or even simpler `$('img', $(this))`

Comment: Or even better `$('img', this)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since `img` is a child of `label` here and [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to get the closest parent that matches the selector. Try this instead:

```
$(".checkbox-cover.images-true>div>label").hover(
  function() {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({top: '-200px'});
  },
  function() {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({top: '0'});
  }
);
```

Also, you can achieve this with CSS only like:

```css
.images-true label img {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  top: 0;
}

.images-true label:hover img {
  top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-cover images-true">
  <div>
    <label> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></img> </label>
    <label> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></img> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just wanted to let you know about it and keep all your options open.